# Scrapping con requests_html

Tags: requests

Estoy accediendo a una página web que permite scraping con requests.
Esa página web primero lanza una pantalla emergente de cookies que creo salvo sin problemas.  Y luego con Javascript carga los contenidos de la misma.
Inicialmente tengo un error a la sentencia:

```
resp.html.render(timeout=20)
```

El error dice:

```
[INFO] Starting Chromium download.
Error al renderizar la página HTML: Chromium downloadable not found at https://storage.googleapis.com/chromium-browser-snapshots/Win_x64/1181205/chrome-win.zip: Received <?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?><Error><Code>NoSuchKey</Code><Message>The specified key does not exist.</Message><Details>No such object: chromium-browser-snapshots/Win_x64/1181205/chrome-win.zip</Details></Error>.
```

Y luego el html de la página accedida vien sin la carga de datos que haría el Javasript.

Utilizando selenium lo he conseguido, pero el caso es que al ser un ejercicio me piden lo haga con requests y estoy aquí atascado.

El código es:

```
from requests_html import HTMLSession
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

session = HTMLSession()

headers = {
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/122.0.6261.113 Safari/537.36'
    }


try:
    session.get("https://tienda.consum.es", headers=headers)
except:
    print("error 1")

busqueda = "cerveza turia"
try:
    resp = session.get("https://tienda.consum.es/es/s/"+busqueda.replace(" ", "%20"), headers=headers)
except:
    print("error 2")
print(resp.status_code)

try:
    #time.sleep(10.0)   
    resp.html.render(timeout=20)
except Exception as e:
    # Capturar y mostrar el mensaje de error
    print("Error al renderizar la página HTML:", e)
    print("error 3")

try:
    html_content = resp.html.html
except:
    print("error 4")

print(html_content)


#soup = BeautifulSoup(resp.html.html, "lxml")
#print(soup)
```